# The university will build a new dormitory ____________ campus

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

*This question came in the Dhaka University admission exam 2015-16*

Q) The university will build a new dormitory ____________ campus

(a) in

(b) on

(c) over

(d) at

I think that the answer is (b), but the question bank says the answer is (a). Which is the correct answer?

Comment: You are correct and the given answer is wrong. The correct choice can only be "b"

Comment: @RonaldSole Understood. If you post this comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you. As **on campus** is a popular expression that anyone can google, I will just leave it as a comment. One does get the impression from several such questions, however, that the examiners need English lessons themselves.